# Error NoProcessFoundForGivenName when trying to activate venv

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, powershell-2.0

Trying to setup a Python venv, but getting this issue in PowerShell. The venv is able to activate normally in cmd. I tried running the shell as administrator, but that doesn't work either. Is there a fix for this?

Clarification:

When I run the command: `PS C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1` I get the below message:

```
Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "C:\> <venv>\Scripts\
Activate.ps1". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:3
+ PS <<<<  C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommand
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Comment: Are you sure '<' '>' and '\' are valid characters for a windows process name?

Comment: to clarify, <> is the path to the script, which I do not want to show. the actual path which I used follows the venv guide, namely this line was what I used:

PS C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1

Comment: When you run a script, it runs in-process in a `powershell.exe` process, so, using `Get-Process` alone, you can only locate all running PowerShell instances in the abstract, but not any particular instance running a given script. Using `Get-CimInstance win32_process` you can determine startup command lines, but that only allows you to identify a script if it was passed on the command line via `-File`.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean mklement0, I have not previously used powershell. To clarify further, when I run PS C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1, the get-process message is shown in red.

Comment: You misunderstood whatever tutorial you were reading. The command you need to run is `<venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1` (or `cd "<venv>"; .\Scripts\Activate.ps1`). `PS C:\>` is the PowerShell prompt, which is meant to indicate that you need to enter the command that follows it in a PowerShell console.

Comment: Never mind my comment, I misinterpreted the error output. @AnsgarWiechers's analysis is correct. You can recreate your symptom more simply by running `PS 'c:\> foo.ps1'`. The `Get-Process` in th eerror message comes from your command starting with `PS`, which is interpreted as a command name, and `PS` happens to be an alias for `Get-Process`.